# xcrun avgtool xcrun: error: unable to find utility "avgtool", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode, xcrun

Unable to automatically update the version number in Xcode using below command

```
xcrun avgtool
  xcrun: error: unable to find utility "avgtool", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Tried below options

1. Added Developer_DIR PATH in .bash_profile and appended to path like
   below

> export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
>   export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$DEVELOPER_DIR:$PATH"

2. Also updated the command Line tools by navigating to Xcode ->
   Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools: selected Xcode 10.1 
   from drop down.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

It's **aGvtool** and not **aVgtool**.

Try to run `xcrun agvtool`, it should be better

Comment: I can't believe I made this mistak

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you have many versions of Xcode or the xcode-select cannot relation with Xcode.
try:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: This fixed the issue on macOS Catalina, even though I didn't have multiple versions of Xcode. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This fixed mine as well on macOS Big Sur, although I only have one Xcode of version 13.1

Answer (score 2):

I updated the command Line tools by navigating to Xcode ->
Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools to resolve above unable to find agvtool.