# Fastlane Apple Generic versioning not enabled in this project

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, bitbucket-pipelines

What I’m doing is trying to make bitbucket pipline do my iOS CD, I included docker fastlanetools/fastlane image and in the steps i pull and run the docker image everything is okay and i was able to let fastlane command work by calling fastlane beta in the steps.

What’s happening is that fastlane exits with the error
Apple Generic versioning is not enabled in this project.

I followed apple documentation to enable it from xCode
[from here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1827/_index.html)
I changed all the targets in my project to use App Generic and still not working

[image: here is the output]

Comment: It appears agvtool is not installed. Make sure this is available in the docker image you are using. See the script output just above the "Lane Context" box. To test your setup, you could try and run fastlane locally first, to make sure your project supports apple generic versioning.

Comment: It is working locally will try to add agvtool to docker

Answer (score 20):

In case it was this issue [xcrun avgtool xcrun: error: unable to find utility "avgtool", not a developer tool or in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499208/xcrun-avgtool-xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-avgtool-not-a-developer-to)

after

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`

fastlane stopped complaining

Answer (score 16):

In my case it was the issue of Command Line Tools, which wasn't specified under the location tab.
[image]

Comment: This worked for me - it seems to be particularly a problem setting up Xcode and Fastlane on a new development machine.

Comment: @Arvoreniad actually I had 2 versions of Xcode at the same time, when it happened for me. But the scenario you mentioned above can be a problematic one.

Answer (score 9):

Add your xcodeproj path.
Like

```
increment_build_number(
    xcodeproj: '../XXX.xcodeproj',
  build_number: number
)
```

Comment: Adding `xcodeproj: '...'` was the only thing that was necessary in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem. I searched and tried a lot of ways, but still not worked it out. A flash of inspiration came to my mind. I set a certain version via `increment_version_number`, it was succeeded magically. Then I tried `increment_version_number` again to make it automatically increment the version number. Lucky me, it worked.

Comment: when you say `increment_version_number`, what does that mean?

Comment: @[Munib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6872794/munib) [increment_version_number](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_version_number/) is  a Fastlane action.

Comment: fastlane increment_build_number

Answer (score 2):

I had two installations of macOS but Xcode only on one of them, after updating I lost the command line tools location. After setting that up in the preferences it worked again

[image: Xcode 12.4 settings]

Comment: that may be one of the reasons

Answer (score 2):

What i missed was missed setting `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION`
(whz. Current Project Version) build setting, *which specifies the current version of your project.*

Reason:

**By default**, Xcode *does not use any versioning system & no value for  Current Project Version*. So setting versioning system to Apple Generic ensures that Xcode will include all agvtool-generated version information in your project.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html)

So make sure, your below set values for

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using this [plugin](https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning) if your issue is not having argvtool accessible in CI/CD when trying to bump stuff uniformly for both IOS/Android before it does it in the macOS runner or action etc

Answer (score 1):

This also happened to me as part of trying to do it in CI/CD. Turns out I was using an ubuntu machine to run the task, and in order to update an iOS app, you need to ensure you are running it on a macOS system

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem appeared after I updated Xcode and my `xcode-select` was pointing to the missing folder.

After I executed `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_13_4.app` Fastlane continued working as it used to before.